# Why are installed components not always available when Delphi starts

Tags: delphi, indy

Delphi 6, and Indy 10.

On Delphi start I get

> "Can't load package C:\Indy10_for_Delphi_6\D6\dclIndyProtocols60.bpl"

and

> "Can't load package C:\Indy10_for_Delphi_6\D6\dclIndyCore60.bpl"

I know the bpl's are where they should be.

After reinstalling the components and reloading the project,
within Delphi, and NOT restarting Delphi, all is fine.

On the next Delphi start, the process repeats.
This has worked well before, and now suddenly it doesn't.

I get the feeling it may be timing issue,
as if the bpl's are unavailable a short time while Delphi starts.
I have seen related posts discussing this (`ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable)`)
but only for later Delphi versions.

I have also deleted the "Disabled packages" key in the registry.

What may be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That usually means dependant BPLs can't be found/loaded by the OS when the reported BPL is being loaded. The Current Working Directory when the IDE is first started may be different than when you go to install a BPL later on. Make sure any relevant folders for dependant BPLs are in your system's search path.

Comment: I added the path to the bpl as Remy suggested. Problem solved. Thank you very much Remy.